# Massive log file and 100% CPU usage for 'upstart'

Tags: 14.10, upstart, log, dbus

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10, and I installed some programs like MATLAB, Chromium, Evolution and other fairly harmless stuff. However, I have run into some trouble recently.

The file `/home/MYUSERNAME/.cache/upstart/dbus.log` grows to an absolutely massive size (over 12 GB!), which then completely crashes my system because I'm working on a tiny partition since I store all my files on another disk, so it just fills up the disk completely and then of course the system becomes largely unresponsive. In addition, the `upstart` process uses 100% CPU on one core, so my clumsily built Lenovo W520 overheats quite quickly as well.

What could cause this behaviour, and how do I fix it?

I ran a `head` and `tail` on the log file. `Head`:

```
myusername@myusername:~/.cache/upstart$ head dbus.log

(process:2372): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1a43550'

(ubuntu-geoip-provider:2409): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '29' is invalid for instance '0x2007620'

(process:2547): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '47' is invalid for instance '0x1b0f370'

(ubuntu-geoip-provider:2409): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '29' is invalid for instance '0x2007620'

(process:2372): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1a43550'
```

`Tail`:

```
myusername@myusername:~/.cache/upstart$ tail dbus.log

(process:8147): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '47' is invalid for instance '0x1b52790'

(process:7836): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1ae2dd0'

(process:7836): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1ae2dd0'

(process:8147): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '47' is invalid for instance '0x1b52790'

(ubuntu-geoip-provider:7859): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '29' is invalid for instance '0x2429e40'

(process:7836): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1ae2dd0'

(process:7836): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '20' is invalid for instance '0x1ae2dd0'

(process:8147): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '47' is invalid for instance '0x1b52790'

(ubuntu-geoip-provider:7859): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:3101: signal id '29' is invalid for instance '0x2429e40'
```